# How to replace specific keys in text file with values in JSON file...not replacing

Tags: java, parsing, jsonparser

Taking input from a text file which contains few keywords which are also present in JSON file as keys. Objective is to replace JSON key with JSON values.

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String entire_txt_file=scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(entire_txt_file);

        jsonObject=(JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/java/browserstackprogramming/drive_map.json"));

        Set keys=jsonObject.keySet();
        for (Object key:keys){
            new_text=entire_txt_file.replaceAll("&"+(String)key+"&",jsonObject.get(key).toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `entire_txt_file` instead of `new_text`

```
entireTxtFile = entireTxtFile.replaceAll("&"+(String)key+"&",jsonObject.get(key).toString());
```

And don't use snake_case, use camelCase

Answer (score 0):

it's not only the case of new_text, Need to check the type of key properly, it could be a type mismatch.key is object type & entire_txt_file  is a string.
please use some log to be ensured about the value of the key for the loop before replacing.